# trying to learning details of recursion

Tags: recursion

I'm learning how to do recursion, and I want to make sure that I'm doing it correctly. I just finished a question on codingbat that reads like this:

> Given a non-negative int n, return the count of the occurrences of 7
>   as a digit, so for example 717 yields 2. (no loops). Note that mod (%)
>   by 10 yields the rightmost digit (126 % 10 is 6), while divide (/) by
>   10 removes the rightmost digit (126 / 10 is 12).

```
count7(717) → 2
count7(7) → 1
count7(123) → 0
```

And my solution, which worked, looks like this:

```
public int count7(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if(n < 7) {
        return count;
    } else {
        int divided = n / 10;
        if(n % 10 == 7) count++;
        return count + count7(divided);
    }
}
```

Even though my solution passed, I want to make sure that I'm working through these recursion problems correctly. Should I have a counter sitting outside the if/else statement? If not, why? If not, how would you solve it instead.

Comment: Should you have a `count` variable in the first place? It does not actually “count” much – it starts out as 0, and then increases a maximum of one times to 1 – so you might as well drop that variable altogether, and have the if return 0 directly, and in the else return 1 + recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more self-contained, the better - and your answer is self-contained. And it has the two requisites for correct recursion:

#### Provide a "stopper"

```
public int count7(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if(n < 7) {
        return count;
```

If `n` is less than 7, return 0, since `n` clearly contains no 7s.

#### Otherwise, assume the problem is solved for some smaller number

```
    } else {
        int divided = n / 10;
        if(n % 10 == 7) count++;
        return count + count7(divided);
    }
}
```

Remove the rightmost digit and assume that the problem is solved for what's left. That's the recursion `count7(divided)`. Meanwhile, what about that rightmost digit? If it is 7, that needs to go into our ultimate answer, so add it in.

So far, so good.

#### Critique

Your structure is misleading. `count` at the start actually does nothing. You could have written this:

```
public int count7(int n) {
    if(n < 7) {
        return 0;
```

In that case there is also no need for your `count++`. We will add 1 if this is a 7 and not if it isn't:

```
    } else {
        int divided = n / 10;
        if(n % 10 == 7) return 1 + count7(divided);
        return count7(divided);
    }
}
```

Observe that that *is* your answer - but it is more "honest" than what you wrote. There was nothing wrong with how you were recursing, but the presentation, I'm suggesting, can be clearer and less crabbed. Your code should read like a verbal description of the approach you are taking: "If this number is less than 7, return 0. Otherwise, pull off the last digit and recurse on what's left, adding 1 only if the number we pulled off *is* a 7."

There are recursion problems where you might generate a "count" value of some sort *and pass it into the recursion call*, but this is not one of them. Thus the whole `count` variable thing is just a red herring.